# How to combine two arrays as key and value?

Tags: php, arrays

In one array there are they keys and in another array there the values. I want to combine these two arrays in a manner all keys of array1 and all values of array2 as shown below. How can it be done in PHP?

**Here are the two arrays**

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => url
        [1] => downloadName
        [2] => downloadType
        [3] => downloadSize
        [4] => url
        [5] => downloadName
        [6] => downloadType
        [7] => downloadSize
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => https://www.clearcube.com/support/controller/downloads.php?id=450
        [1] => F6151 Media Converter System with 100 base TX to 100 base FX.pdf
        [2] => Manual
        [3] => 0.39
        [4] => https://www.clearcube.com/support/controller/downloads.php?id=582
        [5] => G0400147 Rev B.xlsx
        [6] => Manual
        [7] => 0.37
    )
```

**And I need in this format.**

```
Array
(
    [url] => Array(
        [0] => https://www.clearcube.com/support/controller/downloads.php?id=450
        [1] => https://www.clearcube.com/support/controller/downloads.php?id=582
    )

    [downloadName] => Array(
        [0] => F6151 Media Converter System with 100 base TX to 100 base FX.pdf
        [1] => G0400147 Rev B.xlsx
    )

    [downloadType] => Array(
        [0] => Manual
        [1] => Manual
    )

    [downloadSize] => Array(
        [0] => 0.39
        [1] => 0.37
    )
)
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please share what you have tried so far and what error you got while doing so. Stack overflow is not a platform where you post requirements and receive the running program/code. Maybe [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might help you to update your question, so people can actually help you.

Comment: I think your first problem is your array's structure, it is really weird

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of [**array_walk()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) you can combine it easily.

```
$keys = ['url','downloadName','downloadType','downloadSize','url','downloadName','downloadType','downloadSize'];
$values = [ 'https://www.clearcube.com/support/controller/downloads.php?id=450', 'F6151 Media Converter System with 100 base TX to 100 base FX.pdf', 'Manual', 0.39, 'https://www.clearcube.com/support/controller/downloads.php?id=582', 'G0400147 Rev B.xlsx', 'Manual', 0.37 ];

$result = [];
array_walk($keys, function ($val, $key) use (&$result, $values) { $result[$val][] = $values[$key]; });

print_r($result);
```

Working [**demo**](https://3v4l.org/eJt2D).

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [url] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://www.clearcube.com/support/controller/downloads.php?id=450
            [1] => https://www.clearcube.com/support/controller/downloads.php?id=582
        )

    [downloadName] => Array
        (
            [0] => F6151 Media Converter System with 100 base TX to 100 base FX.pdf
            [1] => G0400147 Rev B.xlsx
        )

    [downloadType] => Array
        (
            [0] => Manual
            [1] => Manual
        )

    [downloadSize] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.39
            [1] => 0.37
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

a simple way would be

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array1 as $key1 => $value1) {
    $result[$value1][] = $array2[$key1];
}
```

with verification implemented and independently from the indexes

```
if (count($array1) == count($array2)) {
    $result = [];
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($array1 as $value1) {
        $j=0;
        foreach ($array2 as $value2) {
            if ($j == $i) {
                $result[$value1][] = $value2;
                break;
            }
            $j++;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    var_dump($result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose key array is $arr1 and data array is $arr2 then you can run following loop and create new array by following

```
$new_arr = []
foreach($arr1 as $key=>$arr){
    $new_arr[$arr][] = $arr2[$key];
}
//final array is $new_arr
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use an index based approach, first checking if the length of the arrays are the same.

Loop the keys from array 1 and add the values from array 2 for that key.

```
$result = [];

if (count($array1) === count($array2)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++) {
        $result[$array1[$i]][] = $array2[$i];
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/ghXt3)

Result

```
Array
(
    [url] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://www.clearcube.com/support/controller/downloads.php?id=450
            [1] => https://www.clearcube.com/support/controller/downloads.php?id=582
        )

    [downloadName] => Array
        (
            [0] => F6151 Media Converter System with 100 base TX to 100 base FX.pdf
            [1] => G0400147 Rev B.xlsx
        )

    [downloadType] => Array
        (
            [0] => Manual
            [1] => Manual
        )

    [downloadSize] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.39
            [1] => 0.37
        )

)
```